# Read Microsoft Teams channel messages (Microsoft graph API, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Our organization need to read Microsoft teams messages from customers tenant, but we cannot do this without request access to [Protected API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis), but this is not good for all customers to write the request to Microsoft for backup their messages.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft protects these APIs for a reason, so the preferred method is to utilize the protected APIs as intended. There are a few things you can do instead, for instance using [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-US/connectors/details/shared_teams/microsoft-teams/) to transfer Teams messages to external systems or files where they can be acted upon later. This may limit your actual capability in terms of the information you have access to, and it will come with a price to use Power Automate.

You mention that you don't want your customers to write messages to Microsoft, by which I assume you mean each customer having to request protected API access. If you are developing a system which will call to protected APIs then you are the only person who needs to submit the request to Microsoft. In any other meaning of your concern it's an unfortunately invalid concern because all MS Teams messages are stored on Microsoft servers.